# Почему в питоне нельзя писать анонимные функции в несколько строк?

Tags: python

Как-то странно сделано, из-за этого пропадает почти весь смысл анонимных функций.

Если нельзя из-за табов, то это не проблема, можно же было сделать чтобы с табами прекрасно работало. Например в coffeescript есть анонимные функции в несколько строк.

Может есть другая тупая причина?

Comment: Можно предположить, что логика такая, что если тебе нужна многострочная лямбда - то имеет смысл вынести ее в отдельную функцию (можно вложенную в текущую функцию), но не лепить какие-то гроздья и каскады из лямбд.

Comment: Таков дизайн языка. По сути лямбды - это просто синтаксический сахар как раз для однострочных функций.

Comment: Многострочные анонимные функции реализованы во многих языках, первое, что приходит на ум - js, но я считаю что это понижает читабельность кода, в котором этим злоупотребляют